# JSON to MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a JSON file with data output from another program and i am trying to import this data into a MySQL table with the following two issues.

1. Data never gets put in the table and no errors returned, when i echo out the output and enter it manually into the database it works fine.
2. The data changes from the JSON values when output into the array needed for the sql import string (Values).

JSON:

```
{
"version" : 90200,
"protocolversion" : 70002,
"blocks" : 322877,
"timeoffset" : -1,
"connections" : 49,
"proxy" : "",
"difficulty" : 34661425923.97693634,
"testnet" : false,
"relayfee" : 0.00001000,
"errors" : ""
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("data.json");
$array = json_decode($data, true);
$keys = array_keys($array);
$rows = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $value = $array[$key];
    $rows[] = "'" . $value . "'";
}
echo $rows;
$values = implode(",", $rows);

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'database';
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    if($dbh)
      echo 'Connected to database'; // echo a message saying we have connected

    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO getinfo VALUES ('','" . $datetime . "'," . $values . "");
    echo "Going into DB: ('','" . $datetime . "'," . $values . ")";
    echo $count;// echo the number of affected rows
    $dbh = null;// close the database connection
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```

Info ECHOED out and sent as VALUES:

```
('','2014-09-28 16:11:33','90200','70002','322880','-1','49','','34661425923.977','','1.0E-5','')
```

The first two values are manual entries i created for ID and DATE/TIME

As you can see the output is not the same as input however these values work with a manual INSERT query but not through this script also (hence the two problems).

Comment: For what purpose do you want to store this data? I'd say store the entire JSON string instead of deserialize it and then re-serialize to CSV

Comment: I would like to create graphs from this data over time and figured storing it this way would be better, if stored in JSON then i would need to pull more data than needed and deconstruct on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure I didn't miss anything, these are the differences I notice:

```
| Name       | Actual Imploded | Expected             |
| blocks     | 322880          | 322877               |
| difficulty | 34661425923.977 | 34661425923.97693634 |
| relayfee   | 1.0E-5          | 0.00001000           |
| testnet    | ''              | false                |
```

To preserve the precisions of your numeric data, you can try set the JSON decode bitmask option to [`JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) like this:

```
json_decode($data, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

As for the value of `testnet`, try printing `$values` using `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` (if that's what you have been using). [`print_r()` doesn't show type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873953/1144203); `false` will be shown as an empty string.

Finally, not exactly sure why your SQL insertion doesn't work, but try to change the default error mode of PDO to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` so that any database errors will be thrown as an exception, to ensure you really didn't miss any database errors.

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

By the way, you should consider using [prepare statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

**UPDATE**

To deal with earlier version of PHP where `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is not supported, try of one of the following:

1. Use `preg_replace` to add quotes to integer: `preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+(\.\d+)?)/', \\1:"\\2"', $data)`
2. Increase PHP precision by either adding `ini_set('precision', 20);` to your PHP app or update your `php.ini` by changing `precision = 20`.
3. Use [`ServiceJSON`](https://gist.github.com/itspriddle/845016) like this:

> ```
> $json = new ServicesJSON();
> $var = $json->decode($data);
> ```

Comment: thank you isim, the PDO error mode works a treat and has resolved the posting to the database.

Comment: JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING does not appear to be valid for php >5.5 and the var_dump() function does not appear to work either.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php), `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is available since PHP 5.4.0. I'm assuming you are dealing with earlier PHP version (i.e. php *<* 5.4)? I will update my answer to include ways to deal with that.